# Better method for switching database in rails without exhausting the connection pool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, multi-tenant, ruby-on-rails-6

I currently use this little addition to `ActiveRecord` to allow me to switch databases on the fly:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class Mysql2Adapter < AbstractMysqlAdapter
      # Allows us to connect to a new database in a clean way
      def change_database!(db)
        if @config[:database] != db
          @config.merge!(:database => db)
          clear_query_cache
          reconnect!
        end
      end

      def restore_default_database!
        database = YAML::load_file('config/database.yml')[Rails.env]['database']
        change_database!(database)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I was excited to try the Rails 6 approach to multiple databases but was saddened to see that they have only considered a finite number of databases and those are listed in the `databases.yml` file.

In my situation I can create a new database while the application is running (when creating a new client site) and then connect to it by visiting the domain name associated with the site.

My code above reuses the same connection. I've tried using `establish_connection` but this eventually ends up returning `No connection pool with 'primary' found.` once the connection pool appears to exhaust itself. I'd imagine I'd need a pool with at least the number of databases I have in it for it not to run out, and even then, it still could if there was more than one connection to a site per time period.

My gut is to stick with what I have, but I was wondering if there are any other caches I should be clearing when changing databases mid-stream? (for Rails 6.0 and 6.1)

I should mention that each database is exactly the same structure; it's just a way of partitioning data between customers.

Comment: I want to use this approach for my application but it is not switching databases. I've added change_database! in  PostgreSQLAdapter. I just followed your approach described here github/brendon/switcharoo. I'm using rails 6.1.4.

Comment: So on Postgres, it's actually a lot easier to do this without a hack. In Postgres you can't switch database connections but you can set a 'schema' search path. Essentially you'd have all your core tables in a 'core' schema then each client would have a set of identical user tables in say 'client_1' schema. Your schema search path would be 'core, client_1'. Then when a new client connects you'd change it to 'core, client_2'. Rails has methods for switching schema search paths built in from memory. Here's more: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-schemas.html